# Nodejs express Request body undefined

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, request

I am having trouble reading parameters from the request body for a post request i know this has been asked several times but all the answer are saying to call the body parser before calling app.use() for the routes i did this and also called bodyparser.urlencode() and and it's still giving me undefined whenever i console.log(req.body) or just prints {} ( an empty object)

this is my code

```
const bodyParser=require('body-parser');
const express=require('express');
const app=express();
app.use(
   bodyParser.urlencoded({
     extended: false
   })
 )

 app.use(bodyParser.json())

 app.post('/endpoint', (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.body);
   res.status(400).send({ "ReturnMsg": "User Already Exits" });
 })

 // the port where the application run
const port = process.env.PORT || 6001;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));
```

Comment: how are you calling the endpoint? Can you add the request cURL as well.. or maybe the code for the POST request

Comment: i am using postman just setting request to post and put some data into the body form-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `form-data` is **NOT** supported by `body-parser`, generally `multipart/form-data`(the mime type of `form-data`) is used to upload files. Most API related cases `JSON` or `XML` is used, and when you post a `<form>` from `HTML` it generally gets sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

A one line excerpt from [application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data):

> Summary; if you have binary (non-alphanumeric) data (or a
>   significantly sized payload) to transmit, use multipart/form-data.
>   Otherwise, use application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Now, to **POST** from Postman,

Change the settings to either **`x-www-form-urlencoded`** or **`raw->then select JSON from the dropdown`**

[image: Example]